# How do I do a str_replace or preg_replace on a PHP file?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

If I have an index.php file with str_replace or preg_replace. How can I do a text search on a template file like:

```
str_replace("%title%", "Smart Title", require_once("template/index.tpl"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing Tags with Includes in PHP with RegExps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723188/replacing-tags-with-includes-in-php-with-regexps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of require_once use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
echo str_replace("%title%", "Smart Title", file_get_contents("template/index.tpl"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `file_get_contents()`.Use the code below

```
 echo str_replace("%title%", "Smart Title", file_get_contents("template/index.tpl"));
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: str_replace does not return anything , you need to echo it. Edited my answer